# Does relinquishing lead of fajr salaat to 'Eesa bin Maryam by Mahdi an indication that ameer ul mumineen need not be from progeny of Ali and Fatima?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, prophets

> Hudhayfah reported that the Prophet (S) said, “Al-Mahdi will turn his face to Jesus when he descends as if water were dropping from his hair, and will say to him, ‘Go ahead and say the prayer.’ Jesus will say, ‘The prayer has been set up only for you.’ So, Jesus will pray behind a man who is among my sons. Sirat-al-mustaqim 257, a shia source.
>
> While their Imaam will have advanced to pray the Fajr prayer with them, 'Eesa, the son of Mary may Allaah exalt his mention will descend [at the time of the Fajr prayer]. The Imaam will draw backward so that 'Eesa may Allaah exalt his mention would go forward and lead the people in prayer. However, 'Eesa may Allaah exalt his mention would put his hand between his shoulders and say to him: "Go forward and pray, as it is for you that the call for the prayer was called, so their Imaam would lead them in prayer."
>
> [[Ibn Maajah](https://www.sunnah.com/ibnmajah/36/152/)]

Al-Munaawi may Allaah have mercy upon him said in his book entitled Faydh Al-Qadeer:

> He (i.e. 'Eesa may Allaah exalt his mention) would descend at the time of Fajr prayer at the white minaret east of Damascus and he would find the Imaam (of prayer) Al-Mahdi wanting to establish the prayer. When he realizes that 'Eesa may Allaah exalt his mention is present, he would draw backward so that 'Eesa may Allaah exalt his mention would advance (to lead the people in prayer) but 'Eesa may Allaah exalt his mention would put him forward to lead the prayer and he would pray behind him. So, this is a great favor and honor for this nation. Thus, what is mentioned in this Hadeeth does not contradict what is mentioned in other narrations that 'Eesa may Allaah exalt his mention will lead Al-Mahdi in prayer. This was authoritatively asserted by Sa'd At-Taftaazaani who considered 'Eesa may Allaah exalt his mention to be better, as it is possible to reconcile (the narrations) that 'Eesa may Allaah exalt his mention would first pray behind the Mahdi in order to show that he ('Eesa) descended to be a follower of our Prophet Muhammad sallallaahu 'alayhi wa sallam ( may Allaah exalt his mention ) ruling by his [Prophet's] Sharee'ah (law). Then the Mahdi would be led by 'Eesa may Allaah exalt his mention on the basis of the principle that the one who is less important is led by the one who is better and more important.

**Question:** Does relinquishing lead of fajr salaat to 'Eesa bin Maryam by Mahdi an indication that ameer ul mumineen need not be from progeny of Ali and Fatima?

Comment: Hoestly, I have not heard this hadith before and am not sure about its authenticity in Shia/Sunni source. Besides, according to Shia (and I think Sunni), Isa bin Maryam will say prayer behind Imam Mahdi.

Comment: When Ali bin abu talib didn't offer lead to someone else during his imamate why is Mahdi offering lead of prayer and thereby his title. Sunnis agree eesa will be amir ul mumineen once he descends

Comment: As I said, Shia don't say that Mahdi offering ...  about Sunni view, the answer of https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/8393/iii-ak-iii shows that it is a weak hadith ...

Comment: Read hadith 257 of sirat mustaqeem, Mahdi offers lead

Comment: Firstly, as much as I know, even Sunni brothers believe that there is no garantee that all of the hadiths in their books are completely Sahih. Secondly it is not the viewpoint of Shia to be so. Besides, as I said, Shia's hadiths mention that Isa prayers behind Mahdi, not vice versa.

Comment: You are not getting my point, btw why Ali was not present in Meraj prayer at aqsa

Comment: Ali? Why was not present there? I don't know why, so, it is related to the willing/decision of Allah to be so.

Comment: about your question (Isa...)(about Shia's mentioned hadith): Firstly I didn't examine its authenticity. Secondly, as you see, Mahdi say to Isa "Go ahead", so one of its meanings is = تفضل which shows a kind of respect. E.g., in some/many countries (e.g.), you want to drink water, firstly you offer it to your side-person (to respect), especially if he/she is an old or important person, but it doesn't mean that ..., if you see the rest of hadith, it says that: Jesus will say, ‘The prayer has been set up only for you.’ So, Jesus will pray behind... so it is explicit...

Comment: About Aqsa, firstly, I have not complete info. about that, secondly, but I think: being or not being by the Prophet in Aqsa doesn't prove or reject any specific things, unless we like to interpret based on what we like to ... (it was my view, I respect you view too, کیل الهله)

Comment: Lead of prayer is not courtesy, it's about authority, my larger question will always remain when Ali didn't do it why is Mahdi doing it, Allah preserves revelation so that proof is established upon the rejectors.

Answer (score 2):

**Sunni view**

From a Sunni point of view, the hadith in [Sunan Ibn Majah 36/152](https://www.sunnah.com/ibnmajah/36/152/) you are referring to is considered a weak (*da'eef*) hadith.

In fact, from *Fayd Al-Qadeer*, right after the quote in your question, the author says that the hadith has weakness (وفيه ضعف).

Since there are hadtihs that are either authentic (*sahih*) or good (*hassan*) that describe Al-Mahdi to us, there is no justification to try to deduct from another hadith a different view than what is explicitly stipulated. From a Sunni point of view, there are several hadiths that clearly say that Al-Mahdy will be the ruler and will be a descendant of the Prophet (ﷺ). This hadith tells us the lineage (from the offsping of Fatima), but does not specify whether descendants from Al-Hassan or Al-Hussain:

> الْمَهْدِيُّ مِنْ وَلَدِ فَاطِمَةَ
>
> I heard the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) say: "Mahdi will be one of the
>   descendants of Fatimah."
>
> <sub>— [Sunan Ibn Majah 36/161](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/36/161/)</sub>

The following hadith gives a brief description of some of Al-Mahdi's facial features, then it describes his impact on this world as a ruler:

> الْمَهْدِيُّ مِنِّي أَجْلَى الْجَبْهَةِ أَقْنَى الأَنْفِ يَمْلأُ
>   الأَرْضَ قِسْطًا وَعَدْلاً كَمَا مُلِئَتْ جَوْرًا وَظُلْمًا يَمْلِكُ
>   سَبْعَ سِنِينَ
>
> The Mahdi will be of my stock, and will have a broad forehead a
>   prominent nose. He will fill the earth will equity and justice as it
>   was filled with oppression and tyranny, and he will rule for seven
>   years.
>
> <sub>— [Sunan Abi Dawud 38/7](https://www.sunnah.com/abudawud/38/7/)</sub>

The hadith below tells us his name:

> لاَ تَذْهَبُ الدُّنْيَا حَتَّى يَمْلِكَ الْعَرَبَ رَجُلٌ مِنْ أَهْلِ
>   بَيْتِي يُوَاطِئُ اسْمُهُ اسْمِي
>
> The world shall not pass away until a man from the people of my family
>   rules the Arabs whose name agrees with my name.
>
> <sub>— [Jami' Al-Tirmidhi 33/73](https://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/33/73/)</sub>

From the hadiths above, Al-Mahdy will be:

1. From the lineage of the Prophet (ﷺ) through his daughter Fatima (Sunni view does not specify with certainty whether this will be from the descendants of Al-Hassan or Al-Hussain).
2. His name will be the same as the Prophet (ﷺ): Muhammad ibn 'Abdullah.
3. Al-Mahdy will rule the Arabs, and fill Earth with justice.

When talking about the ruler at large, the Sunni view is that there is scholarly consensus that the ruler be from Quraish (conditional), but need not be from the descendants of the Prophet (ﷺ):

> لاَ يَزَالُ هَذَا
>   الأَمْرُ فِي قُرَيْشٍ مَا بَقِيَ مِنَ النَّاسِ اثْنَانِ‏
>
> It has been narrated on the authority of 'Abdullah that the Messenger
>   of Allah (ﷺ) said: The Caliphate will remain among the Quraish even if
>   only two persons are left (on the earth).
>
> <sub>— [Sahih Muslim 33/4](https://sunnah.com/muslim/33/4/)</sub>

Then, from this hadith, too, the condition is clearly stipulated (sticking to the rules and regulations of Islam):

> إِنَّ هَذَا الأَمْرَ فِي قُرَيْشٍ، لاَ يُعَادِيهِمْ أَحَدٌ إِلاَّ
>   كَبَّهُ اللَّهُ عَلَى وَجْهِهِ مَا أَقَامُوا الدِّينَ
>
> This matter (of the caliphate) will remain with the Quraish, and none
>   will rebel against them, but Allah will throw him down on his face as
>   long as they stick to the rules and regulations of the religion
>   (Islam).
>
> <sub>— [Sahih Al-Bukhari 93/3](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/93/3/)</sub>

Comment: I have added shia source too, armaan says this hadith is sahih as per shia. Can you highlight the text in bold in question  where it says hadith of days al qadeer is weak

Comment: @UmH Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "The Hour will not be established until the son of Mary (i.e. Jesus) descends amongst **you as a just ruler**, he will break the cross, kill the pigs, and abolish the Jizya tax. Money will be in abundance so that nobody will accept it (as charitable gifts). https://sunnah.com/bukhari/46/37  .. someone other than quraysh is becoming leader of muslims

Answer (score 0):

Is the surrender of the Fajr duty to Isa Ibn Maryam by the Mahdi a sign that the Amir al-Mu'minin should not be from the descendants of Ali and Fatima?
Islamic sources accurately and clearly know the birth and personality of the nobleman and the descendants of Fatemeh Zahra (PBUH) and the eleventh Imam from the children of Amir al-Mu'minin Ali ibn Abi Talib (AS) and the ninth child of Hazrat Aba Abdullah Al-Hussein (AS) as well as from the generation and descendants Imams Huda (AS) and the fourth child are the children of Imam Ali Ibn Musa Al-Reza (AS) until the end.

At the time of the advent of that Imam, Christ (pbuh) will descend and will pray in the footsteps of that noble man and behind that noble man. Respect and Christ (AS) says, there is no one who seeks precedence over the Imams of the Ahl al-Bayt (AS) and the right of precedence is with you. [1]
)1(. Safi Golpayegani, Lotfollah, Selected Works, p. 290 onwards.

Ref: https://www.mehrnews.com/news/5103282